# 80s/90s Horror movie about creepy doll with supernatural powers

Tags: story-identification, movie, horror

Back in my childhood in late 90s I saw a horror movie on local TV. I remember just small parts of plot. There was a group of people who stumbled upon an old abandoned house and decide to sleep in there because their car was broken. In the basement they found an old doll, which looked creepy. Then suddenly people started dying. The doll was making some strange noises and then people died because some force dropped things on them / caused them to fall on stuff and so on. There was a fight scene with the doll that was flying above people's heads. One or 2 persons survived and escaped the house and if I remember correctly they somehow destroyed the doll (at least they thought so). Then after 6 months one of them was crossing the road and he saw the same doll in a window of antique shop. The doll was producing same noises again and the guy was killed in road accident by a truck at the same time. That was the last scene of movie.

The picture looked like late 80s or early 90s. The movie did not look like a high budget movie.

Comment: Can you describe the doll? Other than "creepy". Was it male, female, animated, what

Comment: One of these, perhaps? https://www.imdb.com/search/keyword/?keywords=evil-doll&ref_=kw_ref_yr&sort=moviemeter,asc&mode=detail&page=1&genres=Horror&release_date=1965%2C1995

Answer (score 9, accepted):

I think the movie might be [Ghosthouse](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Ghosthouse_(film)). An italian Horror film from 1988.

It differs slightly, the house is not abandoned, it has a caretaker called Valkos, and the protagonists, Paul and Martha, are there because they heard strange screams on their radio and wanted to investigate. They also meet up with four more teens, Jim, Tina, Mark, and Susan who throughout the movie gets killed one by one.

The basement scene matches quite good though.

"In the basement they found an old doll, which looked creepy. Then suddenly people started dying. The doll was making some strange noises and then people died because some force dropped things on them / caused them to fall on stuff and so on."

From Wikipedia

> Later that day, in the basement, Jim encounters the spirit of
> Henrietta, who smiles at him in a macabre way, carrying the clown doll
> in her arms, while the terrifying lullaby music begins to sound.
> Unable to move and escape, Jim begins to scream desperately, just as
> he was heard screaming on Paul's recording from the day before. An old
> and rusty fan begins to move its blades on its own, until one of them
> comes off, cutting Jim's neck, who dies instantly. Right after this,
> Valkos, the caretaker of the house, tries to attack Tina, Susan and
> Mark, who manage to escape him. When the police arrive to investigate
> Jim's death, they wrongly assume that he was murdered by the deranged
> Valkos, implying that the old man has a very strange fixation with the
> house and considers it as his own.
>
> Paul and Martha leave the house and carry out an investigation
> regarding the previous owners of the place. Paul discovers that Sam
> Baker (Henrietta's father) used to work as a funeral director and had
> a habit of stealing personal items from the dead. He also finds out
> that Henrietta's doll was actually a toy that her father had stolen
> from a dead child. Paul and Martha return to the infamous house to
> advise Mark, Tina, and Susan to leave, assuming they are in great
> danger, but things do not go as planned. Finally, all the occupants of
> the old house come face to face with Henrietta's spirit or witness
> strange and supernatural events that result in their deaths. In the
> end, only Paul, Martha and Susan survive the strange and deadly
> events. Before leaving the place, Susan asks who Henrietta was, to
> which Paul answers that she was a normal girl, until her father gave
> her the clown doll.
>
> Later, we see Martha and Paul talking a walk downtown, when Martha is
> shocked to see the scary looking clown doll that Henrietta owned,
> displayed in a store window. The clown begins to smile evily. After
> this, while Paul is crossing the street, the traffic lights abruptly
> go from red to green, which leads to Paul being hit by a bus, while
> Martha screams, horrified.

Comment: Thanks, definitely that is the movie I was looking for!

Comment: Available at Riffrax